# Knockout observable not updating on function parameter

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

I'm new to knockout and javascript. I want to create input value on input box and that value print out on `document.write` but `kotext` value is not updating on `testText` and changing the value on input box. I want keep print out the value to `document.write` and `array push(textKo)` process.

**Source :**

```
<head>
    <script src="knockout-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="line">
        <label>1st Object Name</label>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: kotext1" />
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: kotext2" />
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: kotext3" />
    </div>
</div>
<script>
var AppViewModel = function(){
    kotext1 = ko.observable("No.1!");
    kotext2 = ko.observable("No.2!");
    kotext3 = ko.observable("No.3!");
}
ko.applyBindings(AppViewModel);
testText = function(val) {
    return "This is " + val;
}
textKo = [testText(kotext1()),testText(kotext2()),testText(kotext3())];
document.write(textKo);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're misunderstanding how data-binding works in Knockout.  Instead of using `document.write` ([which is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/1216976)), update the view model:

```
var viewModel =  {
    kotext1: ko.observable("No.1!"),
    kotext2: ko.observable("No.2!"),
    kotext3: ko.observable("No.3!")
}
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
testText = function (val) {
    return "This is " + val;
}
viewModel.kotext1(testText(viewModel.kotext1()));
viewModel.kotext2(testText(viewModel.kotext2()));
viewModel.kotext3(testText(viewModel.kotext3()));
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nZR6A/)

Comment: Thank you for answer but I need each observable's final value with testText function. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @user3436210 I think that's outside the scope of this question.  Accept my answer (you'll even get rep for it!) and open a new question.

Comment: @user3436210 No problem!  Don't forget to click the green checkmark next to my answer

Comment: I have one more question. If I need to use the 3rd party library's function on 'viewModel.kotext1();' (to like Raphael.kotext1()) this part, how can I keep use the observable?